# Is it possible to install SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on Windows 7?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

I'm planning to install SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition on a 64-bit HP workstation.

I read the software and hardware requirements on:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

And according to that page, it doesn't seem that Enterprise Edition supports Windows 7. Is the reference right?

Comment: Why do you need Enterprise Edition on a workstation? That's a pretty expensive license compared to, say, Developer Edition ($59) which does everything exactly the same but with different licensing limitations. Anyway, assuming you want to blow wads and wads of cash on an enterprise license that sits under a desk, I don't think there are any technical restrictions to this configuration, I just think it wouldn't be supported.

Comment: The documentation is correct, you are correct.

Comment: We cannot install developer edition because of company's restrictions, they prefer to pay the enterprise license. I guess they'll have to pay a Win server license as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Previously Microsoft use to block unsupported installations now (I dont remember actually from what version) they have allowed user to go ahead with unsupported installation it will not block it but still the installation remains unsupported. There are some serious limits on windows 7 and you cannot utilize enterprise features so in short don't waste costly license

Comment: @Sean I don't think the document is correct. As I show below, I was able to install Enterprise Edition on Windows 7 without difficulty. Perhaps the document meant to state that these are the *supported* configurations, rather than imply that these operating systems are the only operating systems that will allow installation...

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're correct, it may physically install, but it's not supported at all. Kind of like those trying to use wine, etc, to get it to run on Linux ;) I'm also with you, use developer edition if absolutely needed for something like this (if dev applies to the workload).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in spite of what that document says, you *can* install SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition on Windows 7. I just did it, and there were no warnings, errors, or blockers of any kind:

> [[image]
>   click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDKHR.png)

Now, whether it's supported or not is a different issue (you really should contact your licensing rep), as is whether it makes any sense whatsoever to install Enterprise Edition on a workstation when Developer Edition (which you can typically find for $59 at retail) behaves the exact same way - literally the only differences are (a) what `@@VERSION` returns and (b) what the EULA states about terms of use.

***Note:*** *Developer Edition is now free in SQL Server 2014, you just have to sign up for Visual Studio Dev Essentials ([I blogged about this here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/get-developer-edition)). SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition will also be free once it's released.*

If the issue is that this workstation is going to be in production use, why is it a workstation? You're going to spend thousands and thousands of dollars on SQL Server license, then save a few bucks on a proper server, or spend even less on a workstation operating system? Tread lightly here, because if this configuration isn't supported (or you're using MSDN or grandfathered server/CAL Enterprise licenses and that isn't valid), an audit is going to be very consequential. Please make sure you discuss this with your company's bean-counters and the people who will fire you if this goes south.