# Installing SQL Server 2014 Enterprise in Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit Incompatibility Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

This error occurs when I run the setup.exe of SQL 2014.

[image]

It tried changing the compatibility mode of the setup from Windows 95 through Windows Vista (Service Pack 2) and run the setup as Admin but same error occurs.

I also installed .Net Framework 4.0 and 4.5. Under the Programs And Features > "Turn Windows features On and Off" > I enabled the "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" but I found a **guide** that there should be .Net Framework 2.0 and 3.0 under the Microsoft .NET folder but those 2 versions are missing in my pc.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newmsn/forum/newmsn_install-newmsn_updateapp/i-cant-install-sql-server-2014-on-windows-10/6d311401-796f-4b3f-b5be-d310cfa6454c?auth=1

When I tried installing those two versions I get the following error 
"You must use Turn Windows features On and Off in the Control Panel to install or configure Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2"

same as the SP1 version of .Net Framework 3.0

Comment: why You try install Enterprise edition on the Desktop OS? Short answer - because it not in list of compatible system - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx . If You need it for development purpose - use Developer edition, it work on Windows 7, support most of the Enterprise functions  and it free, if You need it for Enterprise production use - use proper hardware/software.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx - NOTE: For features supported by Evaluation and Developer editions see the SQL Server Enterprise feature set.

Comment: I would also be curious to know why it's not supported? What did Microsoft cripple on their "Desktop OS" such that it can't run their residential SQL database software?

Comment: So my only option is to install Express and Developer Editions? @EvanCarroll I agree,Why is it the Microsoft didn't support this version of their OS even it is the most used version.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would use the opportunity to upgrade to a [real operating system](https://www.ubuntu.com/) and a [real database](https://www.postgresql.org/download/). If that's not an option then may God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Thanks for the info and tips. I am searching for a solution about this for 2 days.

Comment: Developer Edition - cover all what You need, why You try to install Enterprise?

Comment: @a_vlad I am using the 2014 Ent, Version on my Windows 10 pc so I assumed that version is also applicable to previous OS versions.

Comment: are You pay for each logical core? and have on Your Windows 10 512 cores and use petabytes disks? ;-)My question is was - why You need Enterprise Edition on Desktop System? All very simple - Enterprise version is most powerful server from line, and Microsoft - Just DO NOT WANT receive stupid question for support line, for them much easy to tell - if You want use Our most serious tools, please pay for us normal money. Developer Edition - IS FREE!!!

Comment: Yep. "our most serious tools, please pay". They're not serious enough if you do pay. [Get moar serious.](https://www.postgresql.org/download/). Get a database that makes [`foo LIKE "%bar%"` *"SARGable"*](http://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/162263/5)

Comment: This is not religious war PG vs MS ;-). And it fact - MS is very (very and very) successful commercial database. I can explain You much more  - what MS CAN NOT todo, but this is not change the fact - Accounting Software in Our company work on MS but not on PG ...

Comment: @ZeroCool if you have no further questions consider accepting my answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thank you for the information you provided. I installed the SQL Server 2014 after I execute Windows Update and install it for 2 days. Can you explain to me why?

Answer (score -2):

[According to Microsoft you have to pay for these versions of their operating system if you want to run their "Enterprise" SQL Server.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx#)

- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2016 Standard
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 Standard 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 Essentials 64-bit
- Windows Server 2012 Foundation 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Datacenter 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Enterprise 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Web 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 Datacenter 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 Enterprise 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 Standard 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 Web 64-bit

It also seems to run with the same versions in 32-bit, it just stores them in a separate column and amusing Microsoft can't fill an HTML table properly (nor can they generate Markdown-friendly urls.)

Interestingly, "SQL Server Standard"  runs on

- Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate 64-bit
- Windows 7 SP1 Enterprise 64-bit
- Windows 7 SP1 Professional 64-bit

So the question is

**What feature does Enterprise do that Standard doesn't that requires Windows Server 2008 (released in February 27, 2008) instead of the newer Windows 7 Ultimate (released in October 22, 2009)?**

I assume *nothing*, except licensing and marketing wank. It seems you're at impasse, so I suggest [upgrading your operating system](https://www.ubuntu.com/), and [upgrading your database server.](https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

It may also be worth nothing that [other people have managed to do this.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93271/2639)

Sean Gallardy, whose profile claims insider information,

[image: some MS DBA]

[commented on DBA.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93267/is-it-possible-to-install-sql-server-2014-enterprise-on-windows-7#comment167031_93267)

> **it may physically install,** but it's not supported at all. Kind of like those trying to use wine, etc, to get it to run on Linux ;) I'm also with you, use developer edition if absolutely needed for something like this (if dev applies to the workload). - Sean Gallardy

Of course, details omitted we have no idea why it wasn't supported or what the "serious limits" are (from the context of the conversation).. Betting it's still a hold up for more cash.

Perhaps you can *find* a new version of Enterprise without this software-imposed restriction.

Comment: this is Answerr ?!! or one more question? ;-)